Need help in rooting cph1809 (OPPO a5)
I have a CPH1809 RUNNING android 8.1 and coloros 5.2.1
I am completely new in the process of rooting and I can't find tutriols releated to my device if anyone can provide me guide to root my phone

Did no rooting guide for Oppo A5 (AX5) work for you?
